# data pulled from database and displaying unwanted characters

Tags: php

If a full name is submitted to the name column of database and it's pulled onto a web page it adds a + sign instead on the space.

Also if theres a " within the message text that in the message column and its pulled onto a web page it displays a \ before every "

Is there any way of fixing these issues

Comment: Consider using stripslashes (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function..php)

Comment: show your php code, you must be doing something strange like getting data from the query string for a + sign to show up.

Comment: The '+' is because it is [urlencode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)'d.  Use [urldecode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) to convert it back.  And use [stripslashes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) to remove the slashes.  End up with some like `$newOutput = urldecode(stripslashes($fromDB));`

Comment: Check how your data in the database is formatted. If everything is fine there (spaces are spaces and no backslashes) you should look at your PHP code.

Spaces are converted to `+` when using `urlencode()`. This however doesn't explain the backslash.

Do you save the data using PHP?
Could you provide portion of your PHP code that reads the data?

Comment: Either your data is malformed when saving or it's incorrectly processed when read. Or both.

Comment: // sending data to DB
$youremail = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['youremail']);
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
$receiveremail = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['receiveremail']);
$message = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['message']);

$query="INSERT INTO $tablename (rand, youremail, name, receiveremail, message) 
  VALUES ('".$rand."', '".$youremail."', '".$name."', '".$receiveremail."',   '".$message."')";
  
 mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());

Comment: //Receiving data from DB
$youremail = urlencode($row['youremail']);
      $name = urlencode($row['name']);
      $receiveremail = urlencode($row['receiveremail']);
      $message = $row['message'];

Comment: When getting it from the DB, don't `urlencode` it unless you plan on using it as part of a url. Other than that, `stripslashes` will solve your problem ^^

Comment: ok so how would i convert $message = $row['message']; into using the stripslashes

Comment: `$message = htmlentites(stripslashes($row['message']));` (the `htmlentities` being added as part of my answer (below) to display it correctly if printed directly in to the HTML display.  Otherwise, just remove that function call, but keep `stripslashes`. ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code that you added in your comments, expanding my comment in to an answer.  The '+' is because you are `urlencode`ing some of your rows.  [urlencode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) is meant for data that will be part of a URL, what I think you are wanting to do is display it in HTML, in which you would want to use [htmlentities](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php).  But right after pulling from your DB, you'll want to use [stripslashes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) before using the `htmlentities`.

It appears that when you get your POST data, your server is already adding slashes.   Depending on your server version, you'll want to check the [Magic Quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php), and if enabled, `stripslashes` before pushing it through the `mysql_real_escape_string`.  However, since your DB is already set up, it might be easier to skip this paragraph completely and deal with what you already have.

Side note, using 'prepared statements' is a better practice, and eliminates the need to use `mysql_real_escape_string`. ^^

Comment: Would this be correct

$message = urlencode(stripslashes($row['message']));

Comment: I don't think you need `urldecode` as your comments on the question show that you are `urlencode`ing data that comes from the DB, so you would only need the `$message = stripslashes($row['message']);` part of it - unless you want it to be displayed in HTML correctly, then it would be `$message = htmlentities(stripslashes($row['message']));`

Comment: From the edit on the comment _no no no!_, you don't want to `urlencode` anything unless you are putting it in the address bar, use `htmlentites` instead to display it in HTML.